# CSS and JS are not showing

Tags: theming, .info, 8

I just started using Drupal 8 and i am already experiencing problems. In my info.yml file I've added library/ies and in my libraries.yml are those files included. And when I clear cache in Admin, the css is not showing in source code. I've even clear cache in Drush, if that would be the problem but it's not.

Here is my libraries.yml file

```
global-styling:
version: 1.x
 css:
  theme:
   css/style.min.css: {}

global-js:
 js:
  js/app.min.js: {}
 dependencies:
  - core/jquery
```

And here is my info.yml file:

```
name: MyTheme
description: MyTheme template for Drupal 8
type: theme
package: Custom
core: 8.x
screenshot: mytheme.jpg
libraries:
 -mytheme/global-styling

regions:
 header: Header
 content: Content
 footer: Footer
 sidebar: 'Footer2'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like there is missing indentation in your libraries file.

Comment: Any idea how I can fix this ?

Comment: Paste the YAML into yamllint.com or check the YAML syntax in your IDE of choice. For instance, when I paste the info.yml file, I see the line `libraries: "-mytheme/globalstyling"` which means that line is not interpreted as an array, which it needs to be so that is one problem.

Additionally it would be best to use recommended 2-space indentation per Drupal coding standards so that your code is easier to read by community members.

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://ess.khhq.net/wiki/YAML_Tutorial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a space missing between the dash and the item:

```
libraries:
  - mytheme/global-styling
```

And be careful with the indendation. Better use 2 spaces for each level. One space is difficult to see and if you miss one, the whole yaml-file will be invalid.